# Move Vector Path to Fixed Position in Android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, vector-graphics

I've created a custom view for an Android application, and would like to it to display a vector image at a specific point relative to the view's parent. In most cases, it sounds like `path.transform(matrix)` or `path.offset(x, y)` would work. However, the view I've created is animated; if I use `offset` or `transform`, every time the view renders (draws the path onto the view's canvas), the vector path pushes itself further over, and eventually drifts out of bounds.

Is there any way to set a **fixed (not relative) position** on a vector path so that the vector continually is set to the same position?

I've already tried keeping track of whether the location has been set (and not setting it if it has), but since the animation is likely multi-threaded, the condition hasn't been set to true by the time its second frame runs.

Here's what the path looks like on top of the view now:

[image: Current animation at earlier frame]
[image: Current animation at later frame]

As the blue progress indicator gets taller, the vector path goes down (I've set the offset to `(0, 0.5f)` to demonstrate the movement so that it doesn't immediately go out of bounds), but should stay fixed in place at the bottom of the view. Below is the desired result:

[image: Desired behavior]

Comment: `"However, the view I've created is animated"` - what do you mean by that? and you want to prevent/undo that animation or what?

Comment: @pskink Thanks for a quick response! I have a `ValueAnimator` running that updates the height of another graphic I'm drawing on the canvas. I'd like that animation to run, but I don't want it to continually push the vector over. If there's a way to keep the vector fixed in place--have it move to only one point--then that would solve the issue. Undoing the animation might also work, but I'd like the vector to stay in place all throughout.

Comment: ok in simple words: you have a `Bitmap` that is resized/moved/rotated in your animation and you want to draw your `Path` over that `Bitmap` so that it follows it? do i understand it correctly?

Comment: @pskink Close to that--I'm drawing a line of a certain width, and the length of that line increases in the animation. I want to draw a `Path` over that `Canvas`, but not so that it follows it--I want the `Path` to stay fixed at the bottom of the view for the entire length of the animation.

Comment: post your `View::onDraw` method code - it will be much easier to see the existing code

Comment: @pskink Got it--you can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/yprZJ2aa). The code that animates it isn't in `onDraw`, though--I can post that as well if helpful.

Comment: and where is `canvas.drawPath(yourStaticPath)`? i only see `canvas.drawLine` there...

Comment: @pskink If helpful, [here's the whole class](https://pastebin.com/Q0aPP5Jh). Anything named `corner` is related to the `Path`s I'm drawing, which I get from `GoalProgressBar::translateCorner`, and draw on `GoalProgressBar::cutoutCorner`, which erases the path from the `Canvas`. All animation happens in `GoalProgressBar::setProgress`.

Comment: so can you post two images with two different progress values? withot it its hard to analize what actually you want to achieve

Comment: @pskink Thank you--added! I've also included an image of the desired behavior.

Comment: most likely you need `offset(float dx, 
                float dy, 
                Path dst)` - not `offset(float dx, 
                float dy)` - if you use `offset(float dx, float dy)` you will see the "cumulative" offsets - i dont know what is implementation of `getPathModelByName` though... does it return always the same `Path`?

Comment: @pskink Ah, that makes sense. What would I call `offset(dx, dy, dst)` on? And yes--`PathModel` comes from VectorMaster, a library I'm using to fetch `Path`s from `VectorDrawable`s. `PathModel::getPathModelByName` returns the same `Path` every time.

Comment: `corner.getPathModelByName("corner").getPath().offset(rect.left, rect.top, tmpPath);
        return tmpPath;`

Comment: @pskink Works beautifully--thank you so much!

Comment: sure, your welcome - sometimes "wild guess" work... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @pskink's help (see comments above), we found that the solution was an overload of `offset`. I was originally using `path.offset(x, y)`, which directly transforms `path`. Using `path.offset(x, y, modifiedPath)`, where `modifiedPath` is a new `Path`, creates a translated clone of the original `Path`. This means that the original `Path` is never moved, so the effect isn't compounded.